# bind parameters to dynamically update the table name

Tags: python, sql, dynamic, bind, cx-oracle

I am trying to execute a select statement for an Oracle database. In my select statement instead of giving the table name directly , I need to retrieve it from an list of table name only update the designated part and give it in the query.

Tried some code but ended up with error...Pls find my code below

```
tempList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


"Select * from db.vw_fs_{}_all".format(tempList[i])
```

I tried,

```
query = "Select * from db.vw_fs_:name_all"

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = uid, password = pwd)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query, {'name': tempList[0]})
```

It gives me ORA-00903: invalid table name error.

Can someone give me some tips to accomplish dynamic bind parameter in oracle for python environment?

Comment: I've also tried: object_name = Cursor.callfunc('sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name'
                             , cx_Oracle.STRING, ['name']) but I got ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SQL_OBJECT_NAME' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use bind variables to specify a table name (or column name). You would have to do something like this:

```py
temp_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for suffix in temp_list:
    query = f"select * from db.vw_fs_{suffix}_all"
    cursor.execute(query)
```